# How to add our created session encryption algorithm to (major) browser using OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

I am new to OpenSSL and have theoretical information in SSL protocol . I have task to create a certificate who uses RSA algorithm for symmetric session key exchange and use my own my encryption algorithm called `FooSymmetricAlgorithm` for symmetric session key. I need a way to tell the browser and web server to use `FooSymmetricAlgorithm` as symmetric algorithm. I know I can import my root certificate to browser but I think that does not mean I can add my encryption **algorithm** to browser. **My problem is that how I can tell the browser to use `FooSymmetricAlgorithm` for session key and encryption**. It does not difference between browser. It is suffice to have an browser and I will use it just for test purpose.

I want to know that is there any way when I send digital certificate to browser, the browser forced to use my `FooSymmetricAlgorithm` for encrypting data? I mean is there any way to add my algorithm to browser?

Comment: Do you mean you want this algorithm merged into the OpenSSL project itself? Or is this a hypothetical question, of how one would go about getting a ciphersuite added to the TLS spec? Or do you simply want to understand how one would go about adding a cipher to the OpenSSL code base (without the intent having it merged upstream)?

Comment: @StephenTouset I want just test it using OpenSSL.I want to see that is it practical to use my own algorithm in OpenSSL?

Comment: The question is **too broad** to answer… especially since you don’t provide any indication of your knowledge level. As I’m assuming you don’t expect us to write a book, you might want to edit your question and add a few more specifics. While you’re at it: do things like “importing certificates into browsers”, “configuring web-server for SSL support”, or “modifying and compiling OpenSSL” ring a bell? Or does all that sound like a foreign language? I’m asking because, depending on the details, answers will reside somewhere in between all that. By editing your question, you’ll help us answer it.

Comment: Some of this doesn't even make sense. Certificates don't use the RSA algorithm for symmetric key exchange, and you don't use cipher suites for session keys, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that how I can tell the browser to use FooSymmetricAlgorithm for session key and encryption.

You have to add your own cipher suite to the browser, which means changes to the source code in NSS (Chrome, Firefox). Then you have to make changes to the TLS stack used by the server and add the cipher suite there. For details how to do this see the implementation of the existing cipher suites in OpenSSL and/or NSS. Since the cipher suite is not [IANA assigned](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) you have to use one of the cipher-ids marked for private use.

If everything is done correctly the browser will announce support for the new cipher suite and the server will use it. But all this process is not as simple as adding a root certificate, that means it involves lots of coding, reading existing source code etc.

Comment: thanks, can we use s_client command of OpenSSL instead of browser?

Comment: In this case you would need to implement only for OpenSSL and not for NSS too, but the rest remains the same. But given that you ask this kind of basic questions I doubt that you have the necessary knowledge do do all these things.

Comment: Is there any document that helps me for OpenSSL implementation only. I mean how I can add my encryption algorithm and use it for symmetric encryption. the question is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673141/is-it-possible-to-add-our-symmetric-algorithm-to-openssl?noredirect=1#comment41949087_26673141.

Comment: OpenSSL and documentation in this depth? No, you have to read the source code.

Comment: Tank you for your helps any way.