# Is it possible to add our symmetric algorithm to OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to add my symmetric encryption algorithm to OpenSSL and use it as symmetric algorithm in SSL Protocol. I need to test it using `s_client`. So I need a way to say OpenSSL to use it as symmetric algorithm. It is suffice that OpenSSL use RSA for key exchange phase. I just want a way to replace algorithm like `DES` or `AES` in data encryption.

Is it possible? If yes how I can do that? Is there any tutorial for my problem?

Comment: You have this back to front. You don't use a cipher site for a session key. You use a session key for ciphering in a cipher suite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add our created session encryption algorithm to (major) browser using OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672227/how-to-add-our-created-session-encryption-algorithm-to-major-browser-using-ope)

Comment: @EJP I am sorry, I am new to SSL. I want to use my symmetric encryption algorithm Instead of built in symmetric encryption algorithm in OpenSSL. Where I should get start? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. 
Download please latest version (1.0.1j for today) of openssl and look at engines/ccgost folder. There you can find implemented russian symmetric encryption algorithm called gost89 and use them as example (see files gost89.* and gost_crypt.c). Full description how to do this out of this scope. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any tutorial for this? Or it is better I read the code of openssl (algorithm called gost89 you have mentioned)?

Comment: No tutorial at all. You can you use source code analysis technique (e.g. UML sequence diagram). All information about algorithm there is on wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(block_cipher))

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: Did you find any other tutorial on this issue? or could you figure out the solution using this gost89 algorithm?

Comment: @Mjina yes. You can take look at `ENGINE_load_gost()` to understand how gost ciphers loaded in file https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6218a1f57e7e25a6b9a798f00cf5f0e56a02ff31/crypto/engine/eng_all.c. after that look at two main file: gost_crypt.c and gost_enc.c in ccgost folder. I debuged openssl using netbeans and after that it was easy to implement my cipher in openssl.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi Do you have any cbc mode algorithm like des or aes implemented in engine format? (gost does not support cbc mode)